# Calculus 1 : finding the limit with a trig function involved.

Tags: calculus

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}
\frac{f(x) +1}{\sin (x)}=?
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
f(x) =-1
\end{equation*}

The professor gave us a hint; 'multiply by $x/x$' but I'm not sure what to do with that info, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is identically $-1$, the limit is $0$.

Comment: is there anyway you could draw it out? aren't you not allowed to have 0/0?

Comment: @winstonriley if $f(x) = -1$ for all $x$, then $\frac{f(x)+1}{sin(x)} = \frac{-1+1}{sin(x)} = 0$, so then your limit is zero.

Comment: The ratio is not defined at $0$, but the limit still exists

Comment: @winstonriley: Your nominator is absolutely zero but the denominator are still trying to be zero and so the limit gets 0.

Comment: I'm going to bet 3 dollars that the second condition is supposed to be $f(0) = -1,$.  Then the limit is $f'(0).$

Comment: @mrs : what do you mean by 'trying' to be zero?